# Python argparse: how to handle MacOSX `-psn` parameter

Tags: python, macos, argparse, launchd

MacOSX launchd passes the `-psn...` parameter to applications. How can I tell `argparse` how to parse the parameter? It's basically `-psn_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)` but I'm fine if it just parses `-psn(\S*)`. Is that possible at all?

(See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/Process_Manager/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/ProcessSerialNumber) for some documentation about the Process Serial Number (PSN). And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661637/psn-parameter-by-macosx-launchd-what-can-i-do-with-it) is my question about what to do with the parameter.)

Comment: Since it's deprecated, according to the documents, a clean way to handle it would be to ignore it, IMHO. What do you need to handle about the PSN, exactly?

Comment: @Sven: Well, the minimum handling would be to tell `argparse` somehow to ignore it but I even don't know how to do that (I'm not sure if this is possible at all). The next step would be to tell `argparse` to get the part after `-psn_` as the argument of this parameter. Then, the question about what to do with it, is [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661637/psn-parameter-by-macosx-launchd-what-can-i-do-with-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the structure of the **psn** argument, it's not possible to parse it with argparse without interfering with a possible "-p" argument (see @hpaulj's answer). So, I'd recommend to use [partial parsing](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#partial-parsing), and extract it from the list of remainders.

Comment: So, you are basically saying that `argparse` is not able to parse it? Right now, I'm stripping out the parameter in advance because I want the normal `argparse` behavior in case there is an unknown parameter.

Comment: Yes. It looks like one cannot feed regular expressions or somesuch to argparse for argument matching, so stripping **psn** out before or after the parsing seems to be the only viable solution.

Comment: So, to answer my original question: It is not possible via `argparse`, I have to handle it somewhere else?

Comment: The answer by @hpaulj is IMHO a very nice way to handle it via argparse. However, there's nothing useful to do with the PSN anyway...

Comment: Well, not so much for me because it makes `-p` unusable for other purpose, only to have such a hackish solution. Anyway, the simple answer seems to be that it is not possible via `argparse` (that's a bit wrong in your answer: "it'll be annoying to parse" <- it's not annoying, it's not possible). You should make that clear, then I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @Albert I clarified my answer a little.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what other arguments you need (I use Linux), but how about this (from an interactive Ipython session):

```
In [3]: parser.add_argument('-p')
Out[3]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['-p'], dest='p', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)

In [4]: parser.parse_args('-psn_123_455'.split())
Out[4]: Namespace(p='sn_123_455')
```

Then you can parse `args.p` as needed.

You can't use `parser.add_argument('-psn')` because only single letter options can have contiguous arguments. ('-psn _123_455','-psn=_123_455' work, but not '-psn_123_455').

If there are other uses for the `-p` flag, this would not work.

---

You can use a custom `type` to parse the argument, e.g.

```
def psntype(x):
    ret = re.match('sn_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)',x)
    if ret is None:
        raise ValueError('bad -psn argument')
    return ret.groups()

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-p',type=psntype)
print parser.parse_args('-psn_123_455'.split())
# Namespace(p=('123', '455'))
parser.parse_args('-psn_12355'.split())
# usage: ipython [-h] [-p P]
# error: argument -p: invalid psntype value: 'sn_12355'
```

the main advantage to doing the parsing with `type` is that `argparse` can raise an informative error (with usage).  But your own post-argparse code can raise the same error (`parser.error('bad -psn argument')`.

Comment: Well, of course you can do that, but this is a hack and I don't like to not use `-p` for other things because of this.

Comment: Is it any less hacky if I define a `type` that can parse the argument?

Comment: I don't know about Mac tradition, but in Unix, having both a `-p` option (e.g. a print flag), and a `-psn<arg>` option would be confusing.  Normally it would be parsed as `['-p','-s','-n',<arg>]`, where `p` and `s` are flags that don't take arguments, and `n` takes an argument.